# Error: docker build failed: docker build is disabled

Tags: docker

i am running one command on ubuntu terminal i.e:

```
kubectl hlf chaincode install --path=./chaincode --config=networkConfig.yaml --language=golang --label=supply --user=admin --peer=org1-peer1.fabric
```

But i am getting error

```
Error: Transaction processing for endorser [128.199.29.209:30906]: Chaincode status Code: (500) UNKNOWN. Description: failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker build is disabled
```

how should i enable docker build?

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100516/docker-build-is-disabled-error-when-installing-my-chaincode-on-hyperledger-fabri