# docker build is disabled error when installing my chaincode on hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am creating a hyperledger fabric network using the following hyperledger fabric operator for kubernetes https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/hlf-operator I have my cluster configured in aws eks and it is currently running 3 nodes. I am following the documentation and so far all the steps of the implementation are working without problem, but when installing my chaincode it shows me the following message:

```
'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker build is disabled
```

Validate and change docker permissions but I don't understand what I am missing so that it can work and install my chaincode.

I think it may be a permissions error in the eks, I am also validating the permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I finally solved it. The problem is when you create your peer node right now (as of July 28, 2022), the version defaults to `2.3.0-v0.0.2` (you can find this  `kubectl hlf peer create --help` and see the description next to the `--version` flag). This peer version happens to be incompatible when deploying `ccaas` - chaincode as a service. So, the solution is to manually override the version using the `--version` flag while creating the peer node. Peer version `2.4.1-v0.0.4` solved this for me.

Please see the below command while creating a `peer` node for `org1`.

```
kubectl hlf peer create --statedb=couchdb --storage-class=standard --enroll-id=org1-peer --mspid=Org1MSP --enroll-pw=peerpw --capacity=5Gi --name=org1-peer0 --ca-name=org1-ca.fabric --version=2.4.1-v0.0.4 --namespace=fabric
```

Note the above steps apply only when you are using the peer image from `quay.io/kfsoftware/fabric-peer` which is the default image. If you want to use other images use the `--image` tag.  Repeat the same steps while creating every peer node. This should solve your problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the peer image version to 2.4.1 or higher. This works for the hyperledger official peer image. If you have already created the peer with an older version then you can edit the deployment with the newer image version.